# Is there any way to disable joined Telegram notifications?

Tags: telegram

I am terribly annoyed by those "joined Telegram" notifications of contacts I don't even recall.

I am getting those notifications persistently on Telegram Web, Telegram Desktop as well as the iOS app.

I have searched the setting but couldn't find anything.

Is there any hack to disable those?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the push notifications, you can turn those off in Privacy and Security > Contact Joined Telegram.
As for chat creation, the best option is to turn off Contact Sync and delete sen
 If you don't want it creating new chats, you have to turn off Contact Sync and delete synced contacts. 
I try to always follow it with a negative like "but that means you'll have to add any contacts manually."

Comment: This didn't work for me on my Xiaomi phone, do you know why?

Comment: Do you mean you still get notifications? Hm, if you've both turned off the Sync and pressed 'Delete synced contacts' it's supposed to work 100%.

Although I did see some people on Twitter complaining that push notifications couldn't be disabled through the settings menu, might just be a current bug that'll get fixed in an upcoming patch.

Comment: I would like to keep the contacts but disable the push notifications and that didn't work on Xiaomi and it's bin 2 years I think since and it still doesn't work.